# Unable to open href link in selenium python

Tags: selenium

I have a array called accounts which gets all the href's i want, i then want to open each of these, i have tried the following code

```
        accounts = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/signin?')]")
        for account in accounts:
            self.driver.get(account)
            time.sleep(3)
```

But returns

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Comment: You can try to ``print(account)`` to see variable `account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the list of web elements, so you need to first fetch the `href` attribute from those web elements and then hit them.
You can do it like:

```
accounts = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/signin?')]")
for account in accounts:
    self.driver.get(account.get_attribute("href"))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Be careful to address relative urls in the hrefs as well.

Answer (score 0):

To open the *href*, instead of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you need to invoke `get()` passing the *href* attribute inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  accounts = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='/signin?']")))]
  for account in accounts:
      self.driver.get(account)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  accounts = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/signin?')]")))]
  for account in accounts:
      self.driver.get(account)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```